# Динамическая проверка if \ маленькая игра \ Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, разработка-игр, if

Недавно начал заниматься в Android Studio, постоянно обращаюсь для решения вопросов на этот ресурс, однако сейчас я ответа - не нашел.

Задача Общая - сделать небольшую игру на одной активности с тремя "сосудами" которые необходимо привести в определенное положение. Игра считается пройденной, после того как все сосуды имеют относительно одинаковый размер около зеленой линии, не меньше и не больше заданных значений. Проиграна если один из сосудов достигает красной линии.

Задача 1 - сделать постоянную проверку условий if после нажатий на разные кнопки (для выведения сообщения, прохождения игры.)

Задача 2 - сделать вносимые размеры для view элементов в dp, а не px. Так как появляются проблемы при различных размерах экрана в эмуляторе (очень не красиво).

Проблема 1 - к сожалению, я вынужден был поставить условие в каждую кнопку, что смотрится весьма не красиво, возможно, что условие необходимо установить в какой-то из жизненных циклов активности.

Проблема 2 - Все цифровые значения которые я задаю для изменения высоты "сосудов" видимо учитываются как px, хотя как мне кажется лучше использовать dp.

Игра работает, но весьма безобразно, уверен что можно сделать красивее и правильнее.
Код прилагаю:
Разметка:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNameLayout"
    android:textSize="@dimen/basic_textsize"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#ffee72"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
\\ имя на резметке



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCommentary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/basic_textsize"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_commentary"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#44ff76"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout1" />
\\ комментарий на разметке

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/textViewBackButton"
        android:textColor="#ffee72"
        android:textSize="@dimen/basic_textsize"
        android:onClick="onClickButton1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#ffee72"
        android:textSize="@dimen/basic_textsize"
        android:onClick="onClickButton2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
\\ кнопки 1 и 2

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewButton3"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
        android:onClick="onClickButton3"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#ffee72"
        android:textSize="@dimen/basic_textsize"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewButton4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="#ffee72"
        android:textSize="@dimen/basic_textsize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:onClick="onClickButton4"
        />
</LinearLayout> \\ кнопки 3 и 4

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/View2"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewCommentary"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/View3"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewCommentary"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/View2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/View1"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewCommentary"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/View2"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewline1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/line_green"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/View2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="600px"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewline2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="700px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/line_red"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/View2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewline3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/line_red"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/View2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewblock1"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="@string/block1"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/View1"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewblock2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewblock2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewblock2"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="@string/block2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewCommentary"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/View2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewblock3"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_yellow"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/block3"
     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/View3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textViewblock2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewblock2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Активити:
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class test_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView PixelText;
TextView View1;
TextView View2;
TextView View3;

private int a, b, c;
private int x, y, z;
private int result_x = 0;
private int result_y = 0;
private int result_z = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNameLayout);
    Typeface CustomPixelText = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"pixel.ttf");
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton3);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton4);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    View1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.View1);
    View2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.View2);
    View3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.View3);

    SecureRandom random1 = new SecureRandom();
    x = random1.nextInt(39) + 1;

    SecureRandom random2 = new SecureRandom();
    y = random2.nextInt(39) + 1;

    SecureRandom random3 = new SecureRandom();
    z = random3.nextInt(39) + 1;

    View1.setHeight(x * 10);
    View2.setHeight(y * 10);
    View3.setHeight(z * 10);

    TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
    txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block1)));

    TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
    txt2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block2)));

    TextView txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
    txt3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block3)));


}

public void onClickButton1 (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(test_Activity.this, Control_Point_Activity_act1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void onClickButton2 (View view) {
    a++;
    if (a == 1) {
        result_x = x++ * 10;
        result_y = y-- * 10;
        result_z = z++ * 10;
        View1.setHeight(result_x);
        View2.setHeight(result_y);
        View3.setHeight(result_z);
        a = 0;

        if (View1.getHeight() <= 220 & View2.getHeight() <= 220 & View3.getHeight() <= 220 & View1.getHeight() >= 180 & View2.getHeight() >= 180 & View3.getHeight() >= 180) {
            TextView tvb3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
            tvb3.setText("все получилось");
        } else {
            TextView tvb3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
            tvb3.setText("");
        }

        if (View1.getHeight() <= 220 & View1.getHeight() >= 180) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockOK)));
        } else {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block1)));
        }


    }
}

public void onClickButton3 (View view) {
    b ++;
    if (b == 1){
        result_x = x -- * 10;
        //result_y = y -- * 10;
        result_z = z ++ * 10;
        View1.setHeight(result_x);
        //View2.setHeight(result_y);
        View3.setHeight(result_z);
        b = 0;

        if (View1.getHeight() <= 220 & View2.getHeight() <= 220 & View3.getHeight() <= 220 & View1.getHeight() >= 180 & View2.getHeight() >= 180 & View3.getHeight() >= 180) {
            TextView tvb3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
            tvb3.setText("все получилось");
        } else {
            TextView tvb3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
            tvb3.setText("");
        }

        if (View2.getHeight() <= 220 & View2.getHeight() >= 180) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockOK)));
        } else {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block2)));
        }

    }
}
public void onClickButton4 (View view) {
    c ++;
    if (c == 1){
        result_x = x ++ * 10;
        result_y = y ++ * 10;
        result_z = z -- * 10;
        View1.setHeight(result_x);
        View2.setHeight(result_y);
        View3.setHeight(result_z);
        c = 0;

        if (View1.getHeight() <= 220 & View2.getHeight() <= 220 & View3.getHeight() <= 220 & View1.getHeight() >= 180 & View2.getHeight() >= 180 & View3.getHeight() >= 180) {
            TextView tvb3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
            tvb3.setText("все получилось");
        } else {
            TextView tvb3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
            tvb3.setText("");
        }

        if (View3.getHeight() <= 220 & View3.getHeight() >= 180) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockOK)));
        } else {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block3)));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено. Возможно "Грубо" и "Топорно", однако теперь все работает.
Осталась одна проблема, точнее "проблемка", но это уже отдельная тема.
Большое всем спасибо, за помощь в решении этих проблем!

Код приведен ниже:
public class test_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView PixelText;
TextView View1;
TextView View2;
TextView View3;
View RedLine1;
View GreenLine;
View RedLine2;


private int a, b, c;
private int x, y, z;
private int result_x = 0;
private int result_y = 0;
private int result_z = 0;

public int px2dp(int dp){
    DisplayMetrics dispMetr = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (dispMetr.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNameLayout);
    Typeface CustomPixelText = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "pixel.ttf");
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton1);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton2);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton3);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton4);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    PixelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    View1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View1);
    View2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View2);
    View3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View3);
    RedLine1 = findViewById(R.id.viewline3);
    RedLine2 = findViewById(R.id.viewline2);
    GreenLine = findViewById(R.id.viewline1);


    SecureRandom random1 = new SecureRandom();
    x = random1.nextInt(8) + 7;
    SecureRandom random2 = new SecureRandom();
    y = random2.nextInt(8) + 7;
    SecureRandom random3 = new SecureRandom();
    z = random3.nextInt(8) + 7;

    View1.setHeight(px2dp(x) * 10);
    View2.setHeight(px2dp(y) * 10);
    View3.setHeight(px2dp(z) * 10);
    int bottom1 = 40;
    int bottom2 = 200;
    int bottom3 = 240;
    RedLine1.setBottom(px2dp(bottom1));
    RedLine2.setBottom(px2dp(bottom3));
    GreenLine.setBottom(px2dp(bottom2));


    TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
    txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block1)));

    TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
    txt2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block2)));

    TextView txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
    txt3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block3)));


}

CountDownTimer CoumtDownDelay = new CountDownTimer(500, 500) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        CountDown.start();
    }
}.start();

boolean OffOn = true;
boolean NoClick = true;

CountDownTimer CountDown = new CountDownTimer(500, 250) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // общее условие
        if (View1.getHeight() >= px2dp(190) & View1.getHeight() <= px2dp(210) & View2.getHeight() >= px2dp(190) & View2.getHeight() <= px2dp(210) & View3.getHeight() >= px2dp(190) & View3.getHeight() <= px2dp(210)){
            OffOn = false;
            NoClick = false;

            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentary);
            txt1.setText("Все получилось");
        }

        // отдельная проверка кнопки 1
        if (View1.getHeight() >= px2dp(190) & View1.getHeight() <= px2dp(210)) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockOK)));
        }
        else if (View1.getHeight() <= px2dp(40) || View1.getHeight() >= px2dp(240)) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockError)));

            OffOn = false;
            NoClick = false;
        } else {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock1);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block1)));
        }

        // отдельная проверка кнопки 2
        if (View2.getHeight() >= px2dp(190) & View2.getHeight() <= px2dp(210)) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockOK)));
        }
        else if (View2.getHeight() <= px2dp(40) || View2.getHeight() >= px2dp(240)) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockError)));

            OffOn = false;
            NoClick = false;
        } else {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock2);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block2)));
        }

        // отдельная проверка кнопки 3
        if (View3.getHeight() >= px2dp(190) & View3.getHeight() <= px2dp(210)) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockOK)));
        }
        else if (View3.getHeight() <= px2dp(40) || View3.getHeight() >= px2dp(240)) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.blockError)));

            OffOn = false;
            NoClick = false;
        } else {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewblock3);
            txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.block3)));
        }
    }
    public void onFinish() {

        if (!OffOn){
            this.cancel();
        } else {
            this.start();
        }

        if (!NoClick){
            TextView Noclick2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewButton2);
            Noclick2.setClickable(false);
            TextView Noclick3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewButton3);
            Noclick3.setClickable(false);
            TextView Noclick4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewButton4);
            Noclick4.setClickable(false);
        } else {
            TextView Noclick2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewButton2);
            Noclick2.setClickable(true);
            TextView Noclick3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewButton3);
            Noclick3.setClickable(true);
            TextView Noclick4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewButton4);
            Noclick4.setClickable(true);
        }
    }
};

public void onClickButton1 (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(test_Activity.this, Control_Point_Activity_act1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickButton2 (View view) {
    a++;
    if (a == 1) {
        result_x = x++ * 10;
        result_y = y-- * 10;
        result_z = z++ * 10;
        View1.setHeight(px2dp(result_x));
        View2.setHeight(px2dp(result_y));
        View3.setHeight(px2dp(result_z));
        a = 0;
    }
}

public void onClickButton3 (View view) {
    b ++;
    if (b == 1){
        result_x = x -- * 10;
        result_z = z ++ * 10;
        View1.setHeight(px2dp(result_x));
        View3.setHeight(px2dp(result_z));
        b = 0;
    }
}
public void onClickButton4 (View view) {
    c ++;
    if (c == 1){
        result_x = x ++ * 10;
        result_y = y ++ * 10;
        result_z = z -- * 10;
        View1.setHeight(px2dp(result_x));
        View2.setHeight(px2dp(result_y));
        View3.setHeight(px2dp(result_z));
        c = 0;

    }
}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]